# React Select. Muestra la información, pero por la parte de atrás

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-5, react-select

Tengo un formulario en ReactJs, el cual le puse un React Select. Ambos, funcionan correctamente como se muestra a continuación:

```js
<div className="login templete d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center 100-w 100-vh">
                         <div className="50-w p-5 rounded bg-white">
                         
                      <h3>Antecedentes Hereditarios y Familiares-Entrada de Datos</h3> 
                               <div className="input-group"> 
                                     <br></br><br></br>
                              <div className="form-group" > 
                                   <label htmlFor="">Padecimiento:</label>
                                 <input type="text" onChange={e=>padecimientochange(e.target.value)} value={txtpadecimiento || ''}  name="txtpadecimiento" id="txtpadecimiento" className="form-control" aria-describedby="helpId" size={15}  placeholder="Teclea el padecimiento"  >
                                 </input>
                             </div>   

                           <div className="form-group">
                               <label htmlFor="">Familiar que lo padece</label>
                                 <Select 
                                         className='search-line'
                                        placeholder= 'Seleccione Familiar que tiene el padecimiento' 
                                       options={familiares.map(sup3=>({label: sup3.Nom_tipo_familiar, value: sup3.Id_Tipo_familiar }))}
                                  Change={handleSelectChangefamiliares}  
                                 />
                            </div>  
                          <br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br>  

                          <div className="input-group">
                              <span className="input-group-btn">                                        
                          <button className="btn btn-success" onClick={agregarAntecedenteHereyFam} aria-label="">Agregar el padecimiento</button>
                               &nbsp;  
                              </span>                                    
                           </div>   
                       </div>  
            </form>    
                         </div>
</div>
```

El problema, es que cuando carga información la muestra "atrás del formulario" como se muestra en la imagen:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No entiendo, que es lo que pasa. ¿Me falta agregar alguna línea de código al React Select?, ¿Cómo se resuelve esto?. Saludos y Gracias por su ayuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En este caso, solo deberíamos asignar un valor superior al z-index de tu react select. Quedaría de esta manera en tu archivo css:

```
.search-line{
     z-index: 999;
}
```